# Using a Having clause with an outer join

Tags: oracle

I want to use a "having" clause with an outer join, using a column that is used in the outer join.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
  I.CARD_BIN BIN
FROM 
  GE_ICA_BIN I
LEFT OUTER JOIN GE_PAYEE_VALIDATION P ON I.CARD_BIN = P.CARD_BIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN GE_PAYEE PP ON PP.PAYEE_CODE = P.PAYEE_CODE
ORDER BY I.CARD_BIN
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

But this gives me this error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 36 Column: 19
```

Line 36 is `ORDER BY I.CARD_BIN`.

Can someone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

This is not my forte, but I am sure that you need a `GROUP BY` in there.

Also, out the `ORDER BY` line at the end of your statement.  Something like this :

```
SELECT
  I.CARD_BIN BIN
FROM 
  GE_ICA_BIN I
LEFT OUTER JOIN GE_PAYEE_VALIDATION P ON I.CARD_BIN = P.CARD_BIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN GE_PAYEE PP ON PP.PAYEE_CODE = P.PAYEE_CODE
group by I.CARD_BIN
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY I.CARD_BIN;
```

Comment: omg..... i forgot it. i see order by as group by, sorry mate, ur right. thanks for helping me T_T #feelsdizzy